# Excel Condition

Tags: excel, excel-formula, conditional-statements

I want to write a formula in an Excel. This is my Problem. 
A1=4, A2=2 . I need to calculate A3=A1+A2 (6). Ok Well. If I change any of the cells A1 or A2 , I need to add the changed value to the Value of A3. That means If I change A1 as 3 , The value of A3 should be Changed as 6+3 = 9. i.e (A3=A3+A1) . How can I do this ?

Comment: You should be able to do this with VBA (not formulae). Formulae don't 'store' values when they recalculate.

Comment: You can do it, but not with a single row/column.  You need to refernce the previous values added to the current.   So something like B1 = 3, then B3 = A3+B1, going with your example.

Comment: @pnuts, yes.  I was explaining how the desired end result could work with just formulas.

Answer (score 1):

Put the following event macro in the worksheet code area:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim A As Range
    Set A = Range("A1:A2")
    Set rr = Intersect(Target, A)
    If rr Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    Application.EnableEvents = False
        For Each r In rr
            Range("A3").Value = Range("A3").Value + r.Value
        Next r
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

Because it is worksheet code, it is very easy to install and automatic to use:

1. right-click the tab name near the bottom of the Excel window
2. select View Code - this brings up a VBE window
3. paste the stuff in and close the VBE window

If you have any concerns, first try it on a trial worksheet.

If you save the workbook, the macro will be saved with it.
If you are using a version of Excel later then 2003, you must save
the file as .xlsm rather than .xlsx

To remove the macro:

1. bring up the VBE windows as above
2. clear the code out
3. close the VBE window

To learn more about macros in general, see:

http://www.mvps.org/dmcritchie/excel/getstarted.htm

and

[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee814735(v=office.14).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee814735%28v=office.14%29.aspx)

To learn more about Event Macros (worksheet code), see:

http://www.mvps.org/dmcritchie/excel/event.htm

**Macros must be enabled for this to work!**